# In MATLAB classification learner, after exporting a model is it possible to extract the parameters of that model?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm

Right now I have a trained quadratic SVM model in Matlab and I would like to create a program in Python using the sklearn packages that obtains the exact same model. I would like to know if it is possible to obtain parameters such as the kernel or gamma used to calculate the model in Matlab, so that I can later use the same parameters in Python.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

By generating a function of the desired model (upper right menu in the classification learner app) we can check the different parameters that have been used to create the model.